# Google Apps Script returning all files in Drive, rather than files in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a folder in Google Drive, where there are some files. I want to retrieve all of these file information, and that's all I want. There are many other files in other folders, but I don't need them. However, my following code is showing all files' names. How can I limit the result only to the files in the specified folder?

```
//Folder ID
var myFolderId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderId).getFiles();
while(files.hasNext())
{
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

For now, there are only 4 files in this folder, but the log shows the entire file names in my Google Drive. I don't know what I am doing wrong, because I am specifying the folder with ID. How come it is returning every file in Google Drive?

Comment: It works for me.  I did however wrap it in a function declaration.

Comment: Here's my code `function getFoldersFiles() {
  var myFolderId = "...";
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderId).getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext())
  {
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName() + '\n');
  }
}`

Comment: @Cooper - your code works perfectly :) I think you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Your code already works great!*

#### Further information:

Google Apps Script doesn't allow the running of global code as specific functions need to be declared and run, at least, not in the same was as locally-run code. The global variables are static and can not be changed in the runtime.

#### Things you can do:

As Cooper mentioned in their comment - all you need to do is put your code in a function, call the function and you're set. The code works great:

```js
function functionName(){
  var myFolderId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(myFolderId).getFiles();
  while(files.hasNext())
  { 
    var file = files.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

As a side-note: if you *really* want to use a global scope (or at least. use an emulation of it), the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) is available to you, though you'd still have to set them in a function and run a function to retrieve them:

```js
function setVars(){
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('myFolderId', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
}
function listFiles(){
 var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('myFolderId')).getFiles();
 //continue this code
}
```

Comment: Actually I had my folder ID in global variable, which was set on another file. I thought running this file would run all files,, but that was not the case. So, getFolderById(myFolderId) was not working as expected because myFolderId was basically empty. No error popped up and it was returning all files in Google Drive, so I was confused, but that was the cause! Thank you all!